# JavaScript how to assign a new function to original variable via referenced var

Tags: javascript, function, reference

I'm trying to assign a new function to a variable in javascript, via another refferenced variable. I have the following code:

```
grp0 =
{
    "grp0_0":
    {
        "grp0_0_0": function()
        {
            console.log('test', 0, 0, 0);
        },

        "grp0_0_1": function()
        {
            console.log('test', 0, 0, 0);
        }
    },

    "grp0_1":
    {
        "grp0_1_0": function()
        {
            console.log('test', 0, 1, 0);
        },

        "grp0_1_1":
        {
            "grp0_1_1_0": function()
            {
                console.log('test', 0, 1, 1, 0);
            },

            "grp0_1_1_1": function()
            {
                console.log('test', 0, 1, 1, 1);
            }
        }
    },

    "grp0_2": function()
    {
        console.log('test', 0, 2);
    }
}

function replaceFunc(group, names)
{
    if (typeof group === 'function')
    {
        console.log('replace function:', names);
        group = function()
        {
            console.log('something else');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $.each(group, function(name, value)
        {
            replaceFunc(value, names.concat(name));
        });
    }
}

grp0.grp0_1.grp0_1_0();

replaceFunc(grp0, []);

grp0.grp0_1.grp0_1_0();
```

As expected, this outputs:

```
test 0 1 0
replace function: ["grp0_0", "grp0_0_0"]
replace function: ["grp0_0", "grp0_0_1"]
replace function: ["grp0_1", "grp0_1_0"]
replace function: ["grp0_1", "grp0_1_1", "grp0_1_1_0"]
replace function: ["grp0_1", "grp0_1_1", "grp0_1_1_1"]
replace function: ["grp0_2"]
test 0 1 0
```

But i want that last line to be:

```
something else
```

How do i change the original function?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can't. If you really want to do this, you'll have to pass the *parent-object* to `replaceFunc` and then work on that object. E.g. change a property.

Comment: Of course! Now why didn't I think of that...

Comment: Appearntly I can't answer my own questions yet, So i will post the result later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments from Yoshi:

> You can't. If you really want to do this, you'll have to pass the parent-object to replaceFunc and then work on that object. E.g. change a property.

I changed the code to:

```
function replaceFunc(group, name)
{
    if (typeof group[name] === 'undefined') return;

    if (typeof group[name] === 'function')
    {
        group[name] = function()
        {
            console.log('something else');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $.each(group[name], function(n, v)
        {
            replaceFunc(group[name], n);
        });
    }
}

grp0.grp0_1.grp0_1_0();

var parent = { groups: grp0 };
replaceFunc(parent, 'groups');

grp0.grp0_1.grp0_1_0();
```

which results in:

```
test 0 1 0
something else
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Javascript function arguments are always passed **by value**, not by reference. This means that while you *can* change the value of the argument, the change won't be reflected on the caller's side.

```
function test(a) {
  a = 'd';
}

var b = 'c';
test(b);
console.log(b);
// 'c';  <<= the value has NOT been changed
```

When passing an object as argument to a function, it’s really a reference to the object that is passed.  The reference itself, however, is still copied.  This means that while you can’t replace the object itself, you *can* change its properties.

So if you want to change a value inside a function, you will have to pass an object; any change to that object’s properties will be visible to the calling function.

```
function test(p) {
  p.a = 'd';
}

var o = {a: 'c'};
test(o);
console.log(o.a);
// 'd'; <<= the property's value HAS been changed
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I kind of know all this, but somehow I just forgot I could simply use the parent to achieve what I needed.